# Getting Null pointer exception sometimes when creating QBRTCSession with opponents while making calls

Tags: android, webrtc, quickblox

Tried to implement webrtc audio/video call in my application using Quickblox SDK version 2.2.1. Implemented QBRTCClientCallback interface on an Android Service Class. Able to make audio/video calls, but consistency is the issue. I'm able to make audio/video calls, but consistency is the issue . Getting `NullPointerException` sometimes when creating session with opponents while making calls.

Following is the code:

```
QBRTCSession newSessionWithOpponents = QBRTCClient.getInstance().createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponents, qbConferenceType);
```

I'm getting values for `QBRTCClient.getInstance()`,`opponents`, and  `qbConferenceType`.

How can we solve this issue?
Do we have any alternate method to create session rather than `createNewSessionWithOpponents`?
Is this because of implementing QBRTCClientCallback interface on Android Service Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QBRTCClient.getInstance().getActivity() sometimes becomes null and you wont be able to create session in that case since **createNewSessionWithOpponents** method uses QBRTCClient.getInstance().getActivity()

Try adding below code before creating session

```
if(QBRTCClient.getInstance().getActivity() == null) {
           QBRTCClient.init((Activity) context);
           QBRTCClient.getInstance().setActivity((Activity)context);
   }
```

:)

Comment: you added these lines in call activity ?